# Dockerfile weird paths generated by Visual Studio

Tags: dockerfile, clean-architecture, asp.net-core-5.0

I'm using Jason Taylor's [Clean Architecture template](https://github.com/jasontaylordev/CleanArchitecture/blob/main/src/WebUI/Dockerfile) and I wonder why his WebUI Dockerfile is generated by Visual Studio just like below.

It sets `WORKDIR` to `/src` and then copies each project from `/src/ProjectDir/Project.csproj`. What's the point of WORKDIR in that case? Look at `WORKDIR "/src/src/WebUI"`. Why `/src/src`? There is only one *src* directory.

[image]

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0 AS base
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:5001;http://+:5000
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 5000
EXPOSE 5001

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | bash -
RUN apt install -y nodejs
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["src/WebUI/WebUI.csproj", "src/WebUI/"]
COPY ["src/Application/Application.csproj", "src/Application/"]
COPY ["src/Domain/Domain.csproj", "src/Domain/"]
COPY ["src/Infrastructure/Infrastructure.csproj", "src/Infrastructure/"]
RUN dotnet restore "src/WebUI/WebUI.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/src/WebUI"
RUN dotnet build "WebUI.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "WebUI.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "CleanArchitecture.WebUI.dll"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect this is because `WORKDIR /src` will create a directory called /src AND change directories into it. After changing into it, it will copy files from the host's relative src folder and into another subdirectory called src (on the container). So the full absolute path becomes /src/src. You can confirm this by adding `RUN pwd && ls` before the `WORKDIR` and after the first `COPY`.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0 AS base
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:5001;http://+:5000
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 5000
EXPOSE 5001

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | bash -
RUN apt install -y nodejs
RUN pwd && ls /
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["src/WebUI/WebUI.csproj", "src/WebUI/"]
RUN pwd && ls
COPY ["src/Application/Application.csproj", "src/Application/"]
COPY ["src/Domain/Domain.csproj", "src/Domain/"]
COPY ["src/Infrastructure/Infrastructure.csproj", "src/Infrastructure/"]
RUN dotnet restore "src/WebUI/WebUI.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/src/WebUI"
RUN dotnet build "WebUI.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "WebUI.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "CleanArchitecture.WebUI.dll"]
```